# Embebed player can't connect to the network - CURL

Tags: php, flash, curl, streaming, media-player

I've made, using CURL, script that log in to the page which provides free streaming, then with CURL I'm going to subpage with choosen stream to watch.

Everything works fine while script is running via localhost (I'm using xampp), but when I put it on my web server it says that it can't connect to the network. Only thing that looks different is the cookie, on the web server it has not new lines /n. Everything is in one line.

How to deal with it? This is my class, which i use to connect with page:

```
class openTV {

public $channel;

function __construct($channel) {
    $this -> channel = $channel;    
}

function openChannel() {

    $login_email = 'mail@gmail.com';
    $login_pass = 'pass';

    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp); 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://strona/user/login');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($login_email).'&password='.urlencode($login_pass));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://strona/user/login");
    $page = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->channel);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->channel);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    $info = curl_getinfo ($ch);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match('/session_token=\[[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\]/', $page, $matches);
    $return['token'] = substr($matches[0], 31, 8); 

    preg_match('/<object(.*)>[.\s\S]*<\/object>/', $page, $matches);
    $return['player'] = $matches[0];
    //$return['player'] = $page;

    $return['channel'] = $this->channel;

    return $return;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `http://strona/` as your host.

Your server probably uses different configuration that doesn't try to append `.example.com` when it fails to find the host directly, on Linux that can be seen in [`/etc/resolve.conf`](http://theos.in/desktop-linux/resolve-conf-linux-example/):

```
search example.com
nameserver 1.2.3.4
```

Using full domain name (`http://strona.example.com`) or IP should fix the problem.

If not so, try whether you are able to ping (or otherwise connect) from server to target host, it may be an networking issue.

Comment: Well, I put there 'strona' only as example, originally there is http://www.wlacz.tv but still not working. But working perfectly via localhost.

Comment: What do you mean Vyktor? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @user1648759 there's another stack-exchange site for that: http://serverfault.com/